# Systemd service file with docker container raise "failed" state on ExecStop

Tags: linux, docker, service, containers, systemd

I have service file, which starts and stops self-written proxy server.

```
[Unit]
Description=Golang proxy server in Docker
After=network.target docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ooolledj/socks5-proxy
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker container rm goproxy --force ; /usr/bin/docker run --name goproxy -p 12345:12345 goproxy:local
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker container stop -t 1 goproxy
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It work fine, except case when i have to call `systemctl stop goproxy` - container stops, with it service get "failed" state. After that, i can call `systemctl start goproxy` and service is "active (running)" with no problem. I suppose it happens because container process (PID) dies, daemon see, that container process exited and raise error `goproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT`.

```
root@my-test-host:/home/ooolledj/socks5-proxy# systemctl status goproxy
● goproxy.service - Golang proxy server in Docker
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/goproxy.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-08-17 18:05:09 MSK; 881ms ago
    Process: 49618 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker container rm goproxy --force (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 49624 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name goproxy -p 12345:12345 goproxy:local (code=exited, status=2)
    Process: 49717 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker container stop -t 3 goproxy (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 49624 (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 135ms

Aug 17 18:04:58 my-test-host systemd[1]: Starting Golang proxy server in Docker: https://github.com/OOOlledj/socks5-proxy...
Aug 17 18:04:58 my-test-host docker[49618]: goproxy
Aug 17 18:04:58 my-test-host systemd[1]: Started Golang proxy server in Docker: https://github.com/OOOlledj/socks5-proxy.
Aug 17 18:05:09 my-test-host systemd[1]: Stopping Golang proxy server in Docker: https://github.com/OOOlledj/socks5-proxy...
Aug 17 18:05:09 my-test-host docker[49717]: goproxy
Aug 17 18:05:09 my-test-host systemd[1]: goproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Aug 17 18:05:09 my-test-host systemd[1]: goproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 17 18:05:09 my-test-host systemd[1]: Stopped Golang proxy server in Docker: https://github.com/OOOlledj/socks5-proxy.
```

Can you suggest how to make service go to state "exited" on stop or else? It's just incorrect that service become failed - it did everything absolutely right.

I tried many options with ExecStop, ExecStart and ExecStartPre, but i have no positive result on it.

Comment: `code=exited, status=2` Have your code exit with status 0 when killed by signal.

Comment: @stark Your question forced me to adjust the code so that when the signal is received by process, the program exits with code 0, i.e. successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple - add the code to main function to handle any signal with exit-code 0:

```
func main() {

    sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigc,
        syscall.SIGHUP,
        syscall.SIGINT,
        syscall.SIGTERM,
        syscall.SIGQUIT)
    go func() {
        _ = <-sigc
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
// working code below
...
}
```

Now my service stops with status like `Active: inactive (dead)`